# Display a Quicktab content in Colorbox pop-up Drupal 6

Tags: 6, javascript, blocks

I have a quick tab (*Drupal 6*) which contains three tabs. One of it has a table which is larger in size. Hence, when the third tab was clicked I need to show the third table as a **Popup** using **Colorbox**.

I have that table as a node Page and I want to display that node as a Popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Quicktab content is a node or any other internal entity, you can do this by using the colorbox-load class and appropriate href. If you aren't able to alter the links in any of the preprocess functions, you can use JS to accomplish this and use Drupal.attachBehaviors() to add the colorbox functionality.